# How to get ASTR balance via json rpc

Tags: astar

team.
I'd like to get the $ASTR balance of the specific address.
I found that I can do it by calling `api.query.system.account(address)` with polkadot.js, but I have to write the balance fetcher program in Golang.

I checked json-rpc specification in the doc https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc,  but didn't find it.

Comment: If you think the answer is useful, please check it.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, it is:

```rs
http.post/ws.send(payload)

payload = json {
  "id": 0,
  "method": "state_getStorage",
  "params": [key, at] // at is an optional param, the block hash, if you don't provide this, it will fetch the latest block's state
}

key = twox128(b"System") + tweox128(b"Account") + blake2_128_concat(account_id)
```

And you just need to implement this http/ws request in Golang.

For more detail check https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/be259234bfee056bef970ac372e04a74411c5224/client/rpc-api/src/state/mod.rs#L33-L288.