# How to get human-readable ASTR balance in Golang

Tags: scale-codec, astar, go-substrate-rpc-client

This question is continued from [How to get ASTR balance via json rpc](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6249/how-to-get-astr-balance-via-json-rpc).

I understood calculating StorageKey from Publickey is needed.
It seems that calculating StorageKey and decoding rpc-json responses are  complicated tasks, so I decided to use the following the library.
https://github.com/centrifuge/go-substrate-rpc-client

I wrote the following GO code and got response, but the $ASTR balance of the response is different from the one found in Subscan.
https://astar.subscan.io/account/Y29MvHDrJyTiNPWYK5r5LouPdc7kkquZe9c6WfpQLvN4wwj
The response is below. I expected Free field is 246,291,284.31933627.
Free field type is big.Int, so I tried to call String() to convert this to human-readable value, but it showed the same result.
Give me thought about getting $ASTR balance from this response?

```json
{
  Nonce:1 
  Consumers:0 
  Providers:1 
  Data:{
    Free:+1057729064290065319908834850671427584 
    Reserved:+0 
    MiscFrozen:+0 
    FreeFrozen:+0
  }
}
```

The code is here.

```go
pubkey := "0x5c2aa08039c510dbd98643e132a3c82475a09814203d631b44fe530d0208dc66"
api, err := gsrpc.NewSubstrateAPI("https://astar-rpc.dwellir.com")
meta, err := api.RPC.State.GetMetadataLatest()
accountID, err := types.NewAccountIDFromHexString(pubkey)
key, err := types.CreateStorageKey(meta, "System", "Account", accountID.ToBytes())
var accountInfo types.AccountInfo
ok, err := api.RPC.State.GetStorageLatest(key, &accountInfo)
fmt.Printf("%+v", accountInfo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `go-substrate-rpc-client` was no more under maintain.

Here is their account data type:
https://github.com/centrifuge/go-substrate-rpc-client/blob/ccecb66ef9132c2cea5be0d6aab89a8ca8b00851/types/account_data.go#L19-L30

Here is the latest Substrate code: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f0b6e79a8d21856743acc5370b5d5c3271048cb9/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L733-L750

As you can see, they don't have the `sufficients` field.

So there are 4 bytes shifted. Then the scale-codec got a weird result.

---

BTW, if you think my previous answer solved your problem, please mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You answer is really helpful. I solved this issue by defining account data type with the following.
And I marked your this answer, but I couldn't find the green check button on the old post.

 ```type ModifiedAccountInfo struct {
  Nonce       types.U32
  Consumers   types.U32
  Providers   types.U32
  Sufficients types.U32
  Data        struct {
   Free       types.U128
   Reserved   types.U128
   MiscFrozen types.U128
   FreeFrozen types.U128
  }
 }```

Comment: Last time I used that the official advice was to define your own AccountData…